# how to pull a set of records from one source and the remaining records from another source

Tags: sql

i have to retrieve records with source_name = 'health' and 'health_details'.

'health-details' have 100 records, but 'health' have limited records like 10 (these 10 records are present in health_details too).

now, i have to retrieve all 10 records from 'health' and exclude these 10 records from 'health_details' and retrieve the remaining 90 records from 'health_details'. so far i have the following sub-query from a huge query.

```
select case
         when source_name = 'health_details' then cust_number
         when source_name != 'health_details' and source_name = 'health' then cust_number
       end as "custnumber"
from table a
```

Comment: Please add to your question ([Edit]) some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try that, you probably have some identifier that you use to compare the records. I made descr column for that purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  descr varchar(20),
  source_name varchar(20),
  cust_number int
);
INSERT INTO a (descr, source_name,cust_number) VALUES ('abc', 'health_details',25);
INSERT INTO a (descr, source_name,cust_number) VALUES ('xyz' ,'health_details',225);
INSERT INTO a (descr, source_name,cust_number) VALUES ('abc', 'health', 10);
select * from a 
where source_name = 'health'
union 
select * from a 
where source_name = 'health_details' and 
descr not in (
  select aa.descr from a as aa where aa.source_name = 'health'
)
```

Result here is two records:

```
descr   source_name cust_number
abc health  10
xyz health_details  225
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  A general approach uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_number
                                order by (case when source = 'health' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where source in ('health', 'health_details')
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The above is convenient for any number of sources.  For just two, `not exists`/`union all` is convenient:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.source = 'health'
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.source = 'health_details' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.cust_number = t.cust_number and
                        t2.source = 'health'
                 );
```